# How to use python's lmfit for retrieving best constrained coefficient rates of ordinary differential equations (ODE)?

Tags: python, ode, minimization, lmfit

I am trying to minimize a loss function over an Ordinary differential equation (ODE) problem, using python.

This loss function is meant to retrieve the best coefficient rates of a user defined ODE.

Despite my efforts and examples found in the internet, all results ended up with ODEs whose solutions returned coefficient values which were outside of their respective bounds.

I know that this can happen for several reasons: choice of minimizer, bad ODE definition, integration step-size, among other things.

Nevertheless, my major problem is to find an example where the minimizer can support integration "Breaks" in the ODE integration.

For example, if I am interested in a simple ODE model, for example the Prey-Predator ODE (Lotka-Volterra), one rule that must be set is that no populations can achieve negative values.

Therefore, if the ODE minimizer for some given reason returns a negative value for any of the two populations modeled (Prey and Predator), the minimizer must stop its integration.

Nevertheless, as it appears, this kind of rule is not supported by common minimizations, at least for the Minimizer objects of the lmfit that I tested.

Even with the bounding rules setted for each Parameter object, the Minimizers continue to interpolate the data beyond the given thresholds (i.e.: negative populations).

---

For example:

Let's assume that I want to find the best coefficient rates of a Prey-Predator ODE with respect to some empirical data.

In this case, if I use the python's lmfit library for my problem, I could do something like below:

---

```
from lmfit import Parameters, report_fit, Minimizer

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode

end = '\n'*2 + '-'*50 + '\n'*2

def ode_f(t, xs, ps):
    """Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model."""
    if isinstance(ps, Parameters):

        Prey_Natality = ps[r'Prey_Natality'].value
        Predation_rate = ps['Predation_rate'].value
        Predator_Natality = ps['Predator_Natality'].value
        Predator_Mortality = ps['Predator_Mortality'].value
        Prey_natural_mortality = ps['Prey_natural_mortality'].value


    else:
        (Prey_Natality, Predation_rate, Predator_Natality, 
         Predator_Mortality, Prey_natural_mortality) = ps



    Prey, Predator = xs

    dPrey_dt = ( + Prey_Natality*Prey  
                 - Predation_rate*(Prey)*Predator  
                 - Prey_natural_mortality*Prey)

    dPred_dt = ( + Predation_rate* (Prey ) *Predator  
                 + Predator_Natality*Predator  
                 - Predator_Mortality*Predator)

    return [dPrey_dt, dPred_dt]



def solout(y):

    if np.any( y <=0):
        return -1 # stop integration
    else:
        return 0

def ode_solver(t, 
               x0, 
               ps, 
               mode='vode', 
               nsteps=500, 
               method='bdf'):
    """
    Solution to the ODE x'(t) = f(t,x,k) with initial condition x(0) = x0
    """




    r = ode(ode_f).set_integrator(mode, 
                        nsteps=nsteps, 
                        method=method)

    t0 = t.min()
    tmax = t.max()
    dt = np.diff(t)[0]


    r.set_initial_value(x0, t0).set_f_params(ps)

    y = []
    times = []
    integration_time = r.t

    while r.successful() and integration_time < tmax:

        r.integrate(integration_time + dt)


        integration_time = r.t

        yi = r.y

        y.append(yi)

        times.append(integration_time)

        if solout(yi) == -1:
            print('Time stoped at: {0}'.format(integration_time))

            break


    return (np.array(y)).astype(float), times




def ODE_solver_residual_evaluator(ps, ts, data):
    x0 = [ps['Prey_Pop'].value, ps['Predator_Pop'].value]

    model, times = ode_solver(ts, x0, ps)


    # if data.shape[0] <= model.shape[0]:

    #     data.resize((model.shape[0],data.shape[1]),refcheck=False)
    # else:
    #     model.resize((data.shape[0],data.shape[1]),refcheck=False)


    return ( model[:len(data )] - data[:len(model)] )


def residual_dim_reducer(residual_array):

        return np.square(residual_array).sum()

if '__main__' == __name__:
######## 

    dt = 10**(-4)
    t = np.arange(0, 100, dt)

    Prey_initial_pop = 1200
    Predator_initial_pop = 50


    x0 = np.array([Prey_initial_pop,
                   Predator_initial_pop])


    Prey_Natality = 2.6

    Predation_rate = 0.12

    Predator_Natality = 0.401

    Predator_Mortality = 0.0025

    Prey_natural_mortality = 0.001

    true_params = np.array((Prey_Natality, 
                            Predation_rate, 
                            Predator_Natality, 
                            Predator_Mortality,
                            Prey_natural_mortality))

    data, times = ode_solver(t, x0, true_params)

    data += np.random.lognormal(size=data.shape)*0.5


    Param_Names = ['Prey_Natality', 
                   'Predation', 
                   'Predator_Natality', 
                   'Predator_Mortality',
                   'Prey_natural_mortality']

    Populations = ['Prey population',
                   'Predator population']

    for i in range(data.shape[1]):
        plt.plot(times, np.real(data[:,i]), 'o', label=r'original {0}'.format(Populations[i]))

    plt.legend()    
    plt.show()

    import os

    to_save = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'original data.png')
    plt.savefig(to_save)



    print('Creating the minizer object', end=end)



    ################3



    # set parameters incluing bounds
    params = Parameters()
    params.add('Prey_Pop', value= 100, min=1, max=600)
    params.add('Predator_Pop', value=10, min=1, max=400)
    params.add('Prey_Natality', value=0.03, min=0.000001, max=3.5)
    params.add('Predation_rate', value=0.02, min=0.00003, max=3.5)
    params.add('Predator_Natality', value=0.0004, min=0.00001, max=3.2)
    params.add('Predator_Mortality', value=0.003, min=0.000001, max=3.2)
    params.add('Prey_natural_mortality', value=0.001, min=0.0000001, max=0.2)



    fitter = Minimizer(ODE_solver_residual_evaluator, 
                       params, 
                       fcn_args=(t, data), 
                       iter_cb=None, 
                       scale_covar=True,
                       nan_policy='propagate', 
                       reduce_fcn=residual_dim_reducer,
                       calc_covar=True, 

                       )

    fitted_ODE = fitter.minimize(method='Nelder-Mead')


    Optimum_params = fitted_ODE.params.valuesdict()


    x0_optimum = np.array([Optimum_params.pop('Prey_Pop'),
                           Optimum_params.pop('Predator_Pop')])

    Y_fitted, times_fitted = ode_solver(t, x0_optimum, Optimum_params.values())


    Param_Names = list(params.keys())


    print(end, 'Param_Names: {0}'.format(Param_Names))


    ##################

    data = data[:len(Y_fitted)]
    Y_fitted = Y_fitted[:len(data)]
    from sklearn.metrics import (explained_variance_score,
                                 r2_score,
                                 mean_squared_error)


    explained_variance_score = explained_variance_score(Y_fitted, data)
    R2 = r2_score(Y_fitted, data)
    RMSE = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_fitted, data))

    print('Explained variance: {0} \n R2: {1} \n RMSE: {2}'.format(explained_variance_score,
                                                                   R2, RMSE))

    print(end, 'Fitting by Minizer is complete', end=end)

    # display fitted statistics
    report_fit(fitted_ODE)

    print(end)



    ######################3


    fig2 = plt.figure()
    n_ref_markers = 12

    markers_on = np.linspace(0, data[:,i].size-1, n_ref_markers).astype(int).tolist()

    for i in range(Y_fitted.shape[1]):

        plt.plot(times_fitted[:len(times)], 
                 Y_fitted[:len(times),i], 
                 '-', 

                 linewidth=1.1, 
                 label=r'fitted {0} '.format(Param_Names[i]))



        plt.plot(np.arange(len(data)), data[:,i], 'o', 
                 markevery=markers_on,
                 label=r'original {0}'.format(Param_Names[i]))

    fig2.legend()    
    fig2.show()
```

---

The returned values are:

1. Two figures: 
   A) the original data
   B) the original plus the ODE's modeled data according to the best coefficient rates that lmfit returned
2. A table of returns containing fitting measurements and parameters statistical descriptions.

---

Returned output:

```
--------------------------------------------------

 Fitting by Minizer is complete

--------------------------------------------------
 Models fitting error:

 Explained variance: -90.1682809468072 
 R2: -3125.4358694840084 
 RMSE: 785.9581933129715

--------------------------------------------------

[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = Nelder-Mead
    # function evals   = 66437
    # data points      = 364
    # variables        = 7
    chi-square         = 2.2485e+08
    reduced chi-square = 629842.649
    Akaike info crit   = 4867.50583
    Bayesian info crit = 4894.78590
##  Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
[[Variables]]
    Prey_Pop:                117.479436 +/- 16.3998313 (13.96%) (init = 100)
    Predator_Pop:            397.552948 +/-        nan (nan%) (init = 10)
    Prey_Natality:           1.05567443 +/-        nan (nan%) (init = 0.03)
    Predation_rate:          3.46543190 +/- 0.05124925 (1.48%) (init = 0.02)
    Predator_Natality:       0.48528830 +/-        nan (nan%) (init = 0.0004)
    Predator_Mortality:      2.76733581 +/- 0.06777831 (2.45%) (init = 0.003)
    Prey_natural_mortality:  0.03928761 +/- 0.00503378 (12.81%) (init = 0.001)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(Predation_rate, Prey_natural_mortality)     = -0.596
    C(Prey_Pop, Predator_Mortality)               =  0.179
    C(Predation_rate, Predator_Mortality)         =  0.141
    C(Prey_Pop, Prey_natural_mortality)           =  0.127
    C(Predator_Mortality, Prey_natural_mortality) = -0.112
```

---

[image]
[image]

---

This problem came from a didactic example extracted from [here](https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/CalibratingODEs.html):

Any help on the subject would be appreciated.

Sincerely,

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time following your code and cannot guess where the problem might be.  Can you just impose the condition "populations must be positive" on the output of your ode_solver()?

Comment: Dear M. Newville, the example I just gave above uses the condition "population must be positive". The condition is set by using the function named "solout(y)" which returned -1 if any of the population (y) values becomes negative in a given integration step. When that happen, I end up with several problems in the integrator. 1) No convergence of the ODE solver; 2) No correlation assessment of the ps variables; 3) Potential other third party errors (i.e.: concatenation errors).

Comment: If you notice in the second plot above, the small lines (blue and green) are the optimal integral of the ODE with the best optimized parameters (the dictionary called 'ps'). It is easy to observe that it did not converge, and also was uncapable of integrating all the way up to the ~175 time steps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your code and this use of ODE well enough to have any other guesses about what might be going wrong.